# Matplotlib: combining two bar charts

Tags: matplotlib, plot, bar-chart, label, axis-labels

I'm trying to generate 'violin'-like bar charts, however i'm running in several difficulties described bellow...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

# init data
label = ['aa', 'b', 'cc', 'd']
data1 = [5, 7, 6, 9]
data2 = [7, 3, 6, 1]
data1_minus = np.array(data1)*-1

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2, top=0.95, bottom=0.07,)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7.5, 4.0))

# adding left bar chart
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
ax1.barh(pos, data1_minus)
ax1.yaxis.tick_right()
ax1.yaxis.set_label(label)

# adding right bar chart
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1], sharey=ax1)
ax2.barh(pos, data2)
```

[image: violin-like bar chart]

- Trouble adding 'label' as labels for both charts to share.
- Centering the labels between the both plots (as well as vertically in the center of each bar)
- Keeping just the ticks on the outer yaxis (not inner, where the labels would go)

Comment: About your first point, what label do you mean? One for the x axis? For the labels you could try to use a tick formatter to make sure they always have the same length.
And I don't get your third point.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, I believe these changes accomplish what you're looking for:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

# init data
label = ['aa', 'b', 'cc', 'd']
data1 = [5, 7, 6, 9]
data2 = [7, 3, 6, 1]
data1_minus = np.array(data1)*-1

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2, top=0.95, bottom=0.07,)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7.5, 4.0))
pos = np.arange(4)

# adding left bar chart
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
ax1.barh(pos, data1_minus, align='center')

# set tick positions and labels appropriately
ax1.yaxis.tick_right()
ax1.set_yticks(pos)
ax1.set_yticklabels(label)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', pad=15)

# adding right bar chart
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1], sharey=ax1)
ax2.barh(pos, data2, align='center')

# turn off the second axis tick labels without disturbing the originals
[lbl.set_visible(False) for lbl in ax2.get_yticklabels()]

plt.show()
```

This yields this plot: [image: combined bar chart]

As for keeping the actual numerical ticks (if you want those), the normal matplotlib interface ties the ticks pretty closely together when the axes are shared (or twinned).  However, the axes_grid1 toolkit can allow you more control, so if you want some numerical ticks you can replace the entire `ax2` section above with the following:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot

ax2 = host_subplot(gs[1], sharey=ax1)
ax2.barh(pos, data2, align='center')
par = ax2.twin()
par.set_xticklabels('')
par.set_yticks(pos)
par.set_yticklabels([str(x) for x in pos])

[lbl.set_visible(False) for lbl in ax2.get_yticklabels()]
```

which yields: [image: combined bar chart with ticks]

Comment: this is great! thank you so much for looking into this! I pretty much got it with last thing remaining... the y-axis labels are not centered between the two plots.  is it possible to do so?  it appears they're right justified, is it possible to 'center' them?

Comment: You can add `ha='center'` to the `set_yticklabels` call, that should do it.  You may then need to adjust your padding to get them exactly in the right place.